# Chome extension: show page action if referrer url is google

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want the chrome extension page action to show if the referrer url is google but my code is not working.

manifest.json

```
 "description": "Shows a page action if referrer url is google.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "icon-19.png",
    "default_title" : "The referrer is Google!"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "declarativeContent",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {

    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
          if ('document.referrer' == "https://www.google.*") {
              new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()
          }

      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

I want the page action to show if the referrer url is google. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`'document.referrer' == "https://www.google.*"` is a no-op, since you are just comparing two different strings and they will never equal with each other.

In the meanwhile Declarative Content API allows you to show pageAction depending on the URL and the CSS selector, not means you could access the `document` object in the web page.

You need to use [`chrome.pageAction.show`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show), to get the referrer, you could call

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(TAB_ID, {code: 'document.referrer;'}, (result) => console.log(referrer));
```

Comment: Please can you explain further. I still dont know how to implement the code.